# mvc 4 drop down default value selected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to select the default value in drop down list where policyId = 7 but it didn't select that value, what i am doing wrong?

Controller:

```
var pm = new ManagerClass();
IEnumerable<myClass> po = pm.GetDataFromDb();
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Policies = new SelectList(po, "PolicyID", "PolicyName", new { PolicyID = 7 });
ViewBag.Policies = Policies;
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PolicyID, ViewBag.Policies as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "dropdown-field"})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just set the `PolicyID` property on your view model to the value you want to be preselected:

```
var pm = new ManagerClass();
var po = pm.GetDataFromDb();
ViewBag.Policies = new SelectList(po, "PolicyID", "PolicyName");

viewModel.PolicyID = 7;
return View(viewModel);
```

Since your DropDownList is bound to the `PolicyID` property (`m => m.PolicyID`), then its value will be used when deciding which element to be preselected.

Comment: On edit page this works but in add page it didn't work. I am giving the id to model also in add page like you are doing.

Comment: I don't know what Edit and Add pages are you talking about. This has always worked for me. Showing a complete example allowing to reproduce the problem would be helpful in better understanding your scenario.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I've seen quite a few questions that when people put the `SelectList` in the `ViewBag`, it fails to select. Whether that's the casting or whatever, but the remedy is usually just sticking the dropdown in the view model.

Comment: sorry its my mistake i was not passing the model parameter View("ViewName", viewModel); i was just using this View("ViewName"). @Mattytommo i am giving you points also your answer was also helpful.

Answer (score 8):

It's because it's not actually selecting the value in the `SelectList`.

First, to make it nicer, put the items in your view model to prevent the cast (this is better practice too):

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int PolicyID { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Policies { get; set; }
    //rest of your model
}
```

Then populate it:

```
var model = new MyModel();
model.Policies = po
    .Select(p => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = p.PolicyName,
        Value = p.PolicyID.ToString(),
        Selected = p.PolicyID == currentPolicyId //change that to whatever current is
    })
    .ToList();
```

Then in your view, do:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PolicyID, Model.Policies, new { @class = "dropdown-field"})
```

Answer (score 0):

In case that you have a static menu:

1- create the following class:

```
public static class StaticMenus
{

    public static List<string> GetGridRowsCount()
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        result.Add("3");
        result.Add("5");
        result.Add("10");
        result.Add("20");
        result.Add("25");
        result.Add("50");
        result.Add("100");

        return result;
    }
}
```

2- add the following code to your controller :

```
ViewData["CountryList"] = new SelectList(StaticMenus.GetGridRowsCount(),"10");
```

3- add the following code to your view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("MainGridRowsCount", ViewData["RowsCountList"] as SelectList)
```