# Make an Item Selected in dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I have already tried few solution suggested on this forum but none of them worked for me. I might be doing something wrong.
I have a viewModel :

```
public class myViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<StockStati> StockStatiList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<StagingOfferResponse> OfferList { get; set; }
  }
```

Then in my controller I am getting populating OfferList and getting different stock stati from the database table:

```
List<StagingOfferResponse> stagResList = getOfferList();
StockStatiList =  (from s in oContext.StockStati
                                        select s).ToList();
```

The table StagingOfferResponse contains fields StockStatus, In the view I would like to display all the open offers using foreach to he user and then ability to change the StockStatus from the dropDownlist. But initially I would like the value from StockStaus field from StagingOfferResponse to be selected in the dropdownlist for every line.

View :

```
 @foreach (StagingOfferResponse stRes in @Model.stagingOfferList)
  {
      <tr>
      <td>
          @Html.Label(stRes.StockCode)
          @Html.Hidden("StockCode_"+i,stRes.StockCode)
      </td>
          <td>
              @Html.TextBox("QtyOff_"+i,stRes.QtyOffered, new { @type = "number",@class="numberinput"  })
          </td>
          <td>
              @Html.TextBox("Price_"+i,stRes.Price, new { @type = "number" ,@class="numberinput" })
          </td>
          <td>
              @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.StockStatiList,new SelectList(@Model.StockStatiList, "SID", "StatusDescription")
              </td>

          </tr>
  }
       </table>
```

Any help.

Thanks

Comment: show some more code please

Comment: Pleas elet me know if the code snippet enough for you.

Comment: try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16664907/mvc-4-drop-down-default-value-selected

Comment: it works only if there is one record to display (one offer) for multiple offers it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the ID of the selected item to the (SelectList):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.StockStatiList,new SelectList(@Model.StockStatiList, "SID", "StatusDescription",stRes.StockCode);
```

Comment: tried this still same, i even tried :
  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedStatusId, new SelectList(@Model.StockStatiList, "SID", "StatusDescription", stRes.StockStatus));

Comment: (stRes) should contain a property that has a value that maps to one of the IDs in (StockStatiList)

Comment: Yes it is mapped to the IDs in StockStatiList

Comment: What is this property?

Comment: hi, 
I tried using :
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.selectedID, new SelectList(@Model.StockStatiList, "SID", "StatusDescription", 2))
Stil no success, not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Make sure that there are values in (SID) property in (StockStatiList)